# Magento2 Get website_ids in product get api

Tags: magento2, product, api, rest-api, websites

Magento2 get website_ids in product get api means product is assigned to which websites.

This is issue generated in github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5773
, but there still not any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this module because with this you can assign a product to multiple websites and retrieve it in the get API. I haven't totally tester the given case but I think it should work.

https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-Product-WebsiteIds-Api

Let me know if this solved your problem.